# Interpretation in context in a paragraph

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation

> Probably the biggest roadblock to play for adults is the worry that they will look silly, improper, or dumb if they allow themselves to truly play. Or they think that it is irresponsible, immature, and childish to give themselves regularly over to play. Nonsense and silliness come naturally to kids, but they get pounded out by norms that look down on “frivolity.” This is particularly true for people who have been valued for performance standards set by parents or the educational system, or measured by other cultural norms that are internalized and no longer questioned.

Probably the biggest roadblock to (1)**play** for adults is the worry that they will look silly, improper, or dumb if they allow themselves to truly play. Or they think that it is irresponsible, immature, and childish to give themselves regularly over to play. (2)**Nonsense and silliness come naturally to kids**, but (3)**they** (4)**get pounded out** by norms that look down on “frivolity.” This is particularly true for people who have been valued for performance standards set by parents or the educational system, or measured by other cultural norms that are internalized and no longer questioned.

(1) I think "play" is a noun.

(2) I interpret like: Kids think adults who only play is silly.

(3) Who is they? I guess they are adults

(4) What "get pounded out" menas? I guess "get criticized by norms"

My guess above is correct?

Answer (score 2):

1. Play is a noun, the object of the preposition "to".
2. That's not right. It's the adults who think play is silly, and are thus inhibited from playing.
3. "They" are the adults just mentioned.
4. Yes, "pounded out" mean that the "nonsense and silliness" are inhibited by the norms.

The paragraph discusses why the play that comes naturally to kids is no longer natural after they become adults.

Comment: Why kids appeared suddenly? in (2). literally nonsense and sillness come to kids. Should I interpret like: If kids only play, it's silly.

Comment: "Kids" are mentioned because the paragraph says that play comes naturally to them, and it discusses why what was natural for children is no longer natural for adults.